# Rename files in a Windows directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-rename, listdir

I am currently trying to learn python by writing a script that will clean up my downloads folder by preserving the name of the object while removing special characters and extra data from the folder/file name.

i.e.:

```
../Completed Downloads/random.download.here.x264.team
../Completed Download/random download here
```

as well as

```
file.name.randomstring_randomstring.mkv
file name randomstring randomstring (date).mkv
```

I've been searching for a while now, but while I can make a script that sees these files - I can't seem to get it to just pluck out each individual special character and rename it. When I do, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\plexprep.py", line 7, in <module>
    os.rename(dir, dir.replace(".", "").lower())
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

here is the start of my script:

```
import fnmatch
import os

#Matches directories for Plex and renames directories to help Plex crawl.
for dir in os.listdir('F:\Downloads\Completed Downloads'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(dir, '*'):
        os.rename(dir, dir.replace(".", "").lower())

#Matches filenames for Plex and renames files/subdirectories to help Plex crawl.
```

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to do this for me, just point me in the right direction please.

Comment: So you're looking to replace dots in the filename, all but the last dot ?

Comment: well, the way I view my files/directories are so that extensions are shown so .mkv is always present to me. So, I am fine removing all periods from the directory/file name as well as static things like 'x264' or so.

I figure I need to create tuples or a list to run them through, but I'm not quite there in the script yet.

Comment: So, you are trying to recreate [FileBot](http://www.filebot.net/)?

Comment: I suppose so. However I am mainly doing this to learn more about computers and programming, so I probably don't need all that functionality! lol

Comment: Alright, well, I think you should either scape the backslashes, or simply add an `r` to the front this string `'F:\Downloads\Completed Downloads'` like so `r'F:\Downloads\Completed Downloads'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cricket_007 said in the comment, you should escape backslashes by adding `r` in front of the path:

```
for dir in os.listdir(r'F:\Downloads\Completed Downloads'):
```

However the `WindowsError` is caused by the something else: In your loop, `dir` will only be the *name* of the subfolder, but not the complete path to it. A possible solution would be:

```
base = r'F:\Downloads\Completed Downloads'
for dir in os.listdir(base):
    path = os.path.join(base, dir)
    # Now use your os.rename() logic
```